# check uploaded file size in function

Tags: php

i make a function to check uploaded file size. However when i upload a file smaller than permitted size it always output `size is over permit`. Here is my function:

```
$max=150000;
    function checkSize($size)
    {
        global $max;
        if($size >= $max)
        {
            return false;
            //echo 'size > max size';
        }
    }

    $checkSize=checkSize($_FILES['image']['size']);
    if($checkSize==false)
            {
                echo 'size is over permit';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'ok';
            }
```

Comment: please return true in else part for `checkSize` method

Comment: print and check this `$_FILES['image']['size']`

Comment: That should be `return true;` since you're checking if it's over using  `if($size >= $max)` - if true, show error.

Answer (score 3):

Your `checkSize()` doesn't return ANYTHING if the size is ok, which means PHP will auto-return a `null` value. `null == false` is TRUE in php, so you falsely say the size isn't ok:

```
php > var_dump(null == false);
bool(true)
```

Your code should just be:

```
function checkSize($size) {
    global $max;
    return ($size <= $max);
}
```

This way you'll return either `true` or `false`.

Alternatively, you can use the "strict" equality test, `===`:

```
php > var_dump(null === false);
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to use meaningful names in your functions so you know what to expect.  for example is you named your function something like `uploadIsAllowableSize()` then you would better understand it's expected behavior of returning `false` if the size givens exceeds the max.  You also need to return `true` if the size is acceptable. You could do this easily in one line like:

```
return ($size >= $max);
```

You might also consider defining a variable for the max file size rather then using `global`.  This is preferred way of dealing with thing like this that shouldn't change at run time.